# p4 Command line equivalent of "Get latest revision" operation in p4v gui

Tags: perforce

To sync only the current folder in the p4v gui client there is a menu operation  which can be invoked using "Right Click on the sub Folder" -> "Get Latest Revision" which is bind to "Ctrl + Shift + G".

How to perform the equivalent operation using **p4** command line tool ?

Answer (score 9):

Use `p4 sync` to get the latest revision of a set of files.

If you want to get the latest revision of the files in just a single sub-folder, use `p4 sync //depot/path/to/sub/folder/...` or `p4 sync /path/to/my/workspace/folder/...` (These are called "depot syntax", and "local syntax", respectively; there is also "client syntax", as in `p4 sync //my-client-name/my/folder/name/...`)